# Allow full screen in Youtube video (Joomla module)

Tags: joomla, youtube, embed

I need to allow the full screen button in embeded youtube videos.

I have this following module but I don't know how to edit it. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Screenshot of the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmRCD.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckv9z.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR24u.jpg

Comment: 1. Code should NEVER be posted as an image.  2. Question details all belong in the question and NEVER as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Joomla. The following HTML code worked for me.

```
<iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/4liKzXo2lRM?rel=0&autoplay=1" allow="autoplay; allowfullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

A video of it working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RP5G2OaLpB4